# How to parse a number in ruby with a comma ',' separator and period delimiter

Tags: ruby, number-formatting

I am receiving input data in a file that has European delimiters and separators for numeric data, so for example I receive 123.456,78 (where an American would write 123,456.78)

Is there a standard Ruby (not Rails) way to parse these numbers?  Of course I could do string substitution but it seems kind of clunky.

Comment: What is your desired result ? Do you have both situations, or just European style ?

Comment: I have both situations.  Some input files are formatted European style, some American style, but I know ahead of time which style I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`money`](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem.

```
"123.456,78".to_money
#=> #<Money fractional:12345678 currency:USD>
"123,456.78".to_money
#=> #<Money fractional:12345678 currency:USD>
"123,456.78".to_money.to_s
#=> "123456.78"
```

Do not know if that is convenient way in terms of your goals, but it is a decent tool when it comes to parsing  "money" strings.

Comment: they have extracted this into the Monetize gem  https://github.com/RubyMoney/monetize

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is always well-formed and has 2 decimal places, this would be enough:

```
"123.456,78".gsub(/[,.]/,'').to_i / 100.0
# => 123456.78
```

Comment: That's just asking for trouble :/